# Where does the index reside?

Tags: git

For a git repository, say its working directory is `working-dir` on a hard drive.

Then the git repository resides in `working-dir/.git`.

Where does the index reside? Does it reside somewhere in `working-dir/.git`, or in the main memory?

Answer (score 3):

The index file is in `.git/index`.

Looking at it directly will not be helpful, though, since it's a binary file.  You can see the contents of the index by running `git ls-files --stage`.  For example:

```
100644 a8233120f6ad708f843d861ce2b7228ec4e3dec6 0   README
100644 3697d64be941a53d4ae8f6a271e4e3fa56b022cc 0   branch_file.txt
120000 c0528fd6cc988c0a40ce0be11bc192fc8dc5346e 0   link_to_new.txt
100644 a71586c1dfe8a71c6cbf6c129f404c5642ff31bd 0   new.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing that trips a lot of people up is, the index gets referred to as a "staging area", and they infer from that that there's some separate place where indexed content gets stored.  That is not true.  `git add` puts content in the repository and updates the entry for its path in the index, which is just a manifest, a pathname-indexed and lightly annotated list of id's for repository content.  The index gets referred to as a "staging area" only because it is, much of the time, *useful to regard it that way*.

Comment: thanks. is an index for a repository the same as an index for a database? Is the concept of index in version control repositories and the concept of index in databases the same?

Comment: I'm teetering between "yes, they're the same" and "they're very similar", but I think the real answer here is "don't think about git in the abstract. git is not abstract. Learn what's really in the index and use it for the useful things you can do with it."

Comment: Thanks. Can you recommend some book that explains git's index in a way similar to database books explaining a database' index?

Comment: @Tim *Pro Git - Git Internals* may help.